# After clicking on the submit button. The next window is blank, how can I display the data?(This is for a password manager project)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
    import tkinter.messagebox
    import time
    import mysql.connector
    #to save the passwords in mysql
    b=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='root')
    import random
    import tkinter as tk
    def submit1():
        x=b.cursor()
        x.execute('create database if not exists passwords ')
        x.execute('use passwords')
        x.execute('create table IF NOT EXISTS mpass(mpass varchar(25))')
    #master password to access usernames and passwords
        x.execute("insert into mpass values('pws')")
        x.execute('select mpass from mpass')
        y=x.fetchall()[0][0]
        print(y)
        if entry1.get()==y:
            print('ogay')
            continue1()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("wrong password",  "Wait for 10 seconds")
            time.sleep(10)
    root=tk.Tk()
    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
    canvas1.pack()
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text='master password')
    label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
    canvas1.create_window(200, 25, window=label1) 
    entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
    canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)
    button1 = tk.Button(text='submit', command=submit1, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)
    frame1=tk.Frame(root)
    #to store entry values
    name_var=tk.StringVar()
    passw_var=tk.StringVar()
    webs_var=tk.StringVar()
    #new window-showing blank( supposed to have 3 data entry fields and 3 buttons)
    def continue1():
        newWindow = tk.Toplevel(frame1)
        newWindow.title("Password Manager")
        newWindow.config(padx=50, pady=50, bg='white')
    #to generate random password for user
        def random_password():
            letters = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
            numbers = list('0123456789')
            symbols = list('!@#$%^&*()_+')
            letters_lower = list(map(str.lower,letters))
            letters.extend(letters_lower)
            num_letters = random.randrange(8,10)
            num_numbers = random.randrange(1,2)
            num_symbols = random.randrange(1,2)
            rand_letters = [random.choice(letters) for i in range(num_letters)]
            rand_numbers = [random.choice(numbers) for i in range(num_numbers)]
            rand_symbols = [random.choice(symbols) for i in range(num_symbols)]
            created_password = rand_letters + rand_numbers + rand_symbols
            random.shuffle(created_password)
            created_password = ''.join(created_password)
            passw_entry.insert(0, created_password)
  
        def submit():
            name=name_var.get()
            website=webs_var.get()
            x=b.cursor()
            x.execute('create database if not exists passwords ')
            x.execute('use passwords')
            x.execute('create table IF NOT EXISTS passwords(username varchar(25),password 
varchar(25))')
            x.execute("insert into passwords values('{}','{}')".format(name,password))
            x.execute('create table IF NOT EXISTS websites(username varchar(25),website varchar(25))')
            x.execute("insert into websites values('{}','{}')".format(name,webs_var))
            b.commit() 
            passw_entry.delete(0)
    
        def search():
            x=b.cursor()
            x.execute('create database if not exists passwords ')
            x.execute('use passwords')
            x.execute('select username from passwords')        
            print(x.fetchall())
            n=int(input('Enter the username:'))
            x.execute('select * from passwords where username={}'.format(n))
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("output",  print(x.fetchall()))
            x.execute('select * from websites where username={}'.format(n))
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("output",  print(x.fetchall()))
            b.commit()
        website_label = tk.Label(frame1, text = 'website', font=('calibre',10, 'bold'))  
        website_entry = tk.Entry(frame1,textvariable =webs_var , font=('calibre',10,'normal'))
        name_label = tk.Label(frame1, text = 'Username', font=('calibre',10, 'bold'))  
        name_entry = tk.Entry(frame1,textvariable = name_var, font=('calibre',10,'normal'))  
        passw_label = tk.Label(frame1, text = 'Password', font = ('calibre',10,'bold'))  
        passw_entry=tk.Entry(frame1, textvariable = passw_var, font = ('calibre',10,'normal'), show = '*')  
        sub_btn=tk.Button(frame1,text = 'Submit', command = submit)
        name_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
        name_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)
        passw_label.grid(row=2,column=0)
        passw_entry.grid(row=2,column=1)
        sub_btn.grid(row=2,column=2)
        website_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
        website_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
        password_button = tk.Button(frame1,text='Generate Password', bg='grey', command=random_password)
        password_button.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='EW')
        button = tk.Button(frame1,text='Search', bg='grey',command=search)
        button.grid(row=2,column=3,columnspan=1,sticky='EW')
    root.mainloop()
```

I used frame to try and use pack and grid together.

Comment: Don't post your entire code here, rather post the important/relevant part only

Comment: oh okay but 3/4th of the code doesn't run and its linked to the beginning

Comment: You create `frame1` as child of `root` and it is invisible.  Then widgets including the toplevel created inside `newWindow` are children of `frame1`, so nothing will be shown in the new window.  Also from the security point of view, you should create the database and tables outside the application and don't save plain password in table.